# Some _atomic elements' TreeForm looks confusing with Level in appearance

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting, trees

```
In[1]:= Level[1/2,{-1}]
Out[1]= {1/2}

TreeForm[1/2]
```

[image]

---

```
In[2]:= Level[1/2,{-1}]
Out[2]= {1/2}

In[3]:= Level[Unevaluated[1/2],{-1}]
Out[3]= {1,2,-1}

In[4]:= 1/2//FullForm
Out[5]//FullForm= Rational[1,2]
```

Rational[1,2] in TreeForm,but Times[1,Power[2,-1]] when Level.

```
In[5]:= Level[Unevaluated[1/2],{-1},Heads->True]
Out[5]= {Times,1,Power,2,-1}
```

How to comprehend this?
How to obtain `TreeForm[Hold@Unevaluated[1/2]]` without Hold and Uevaluated in whole TreeForm's graph or `TreeForm@{{{Hold[1/2],b}},b,c}` with out hold?
[image]

And How to get {1,2} from Level[1/2, {-1}]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [evaluation leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723277/618728) in `TreeForm` that requires a double-`Unevaluated` to circumvent:

```
TreeForm[Unevaluated @ Unevaluated[1/2]]
```

[image]

The second question is more troublesome.  Because `Rational` is an atomic object `Level` does not extract its conceptual sub-parts.  This is true of other atomic objects as well:

```
sa = SparseArray @ Range @ 5;
Level[sa, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {SparseArray[<5>,{5}]}
> ```

The only thing I can think of is a conversion to held `FullForm` as follows:

```
Level[MakeExpression @ ToBoxes @ FullForm[1/2], {-1}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2}
> ```

```
Level[MakeExpression @ ToBoxes @ FullForm[sa], {-1}]
```

> ```
> {Automatic, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
> ```

Comment: `{Numerator[1/2], Denominator[1/2]}` seems a more straightforward way to get the parts, unless one insists on using `Level`

Comment: @Aky I interpret the question as specifically "insisting on `Level`" rather than generically splitting a `Rational` object; I think `Rational` is only one example.

Comment: @MrWizard That makes sense. When I wrote that, I hadn't realised that your technique could be used with other atomic expressions too. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MrWizard Is there any advantage to using `ToBoxes` vs. `ToString`? (I don't actually know anything about "boxes" yet, but just asking.)

Comment: @Aky I updated my answer to make that more apparent.  I changed from using `ToString` to `ToBoxes` because the latter should be more robust: *any* expression can be represented in Box form while certain things may be changed/lost in the string conversion.

Comment: ha, I think this should be researched by someone before, you did it, I never thought I would use two `Unevaluated` before.

Comment: @Aky as Mr.Wizard said, Numberater[1/2+a] would be failed, for this is an generic question rather than the case 1/2.

Comment: @HyperGroups yeah I got that now, thanks ;)

Comment: @HyperGroups see Leonid's comments under the StackOverflow post I linked.  One `Unevaluated` should have been sufficient but somewhere in `TreeForm` there is an evaluation leak which is stopped by the inner `Unevaluated`.