# Unevaluated @ {args} versus Unevaluated /@ {args}

Tags: evaluation, functional-style

Working my way through [Robby Villegas's lovely notes on withholding evaluation](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/), I *almost* got [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) on my first try.  Here is my final solution, which seems to work well enough:

```
ClearAll[lispify];
SetAttributes[lispify, HoldAll];
lispify[h_[args___]] :=
  Prepend[
   lispify /@ Unevaluated @ {args},
   lispify[h]];
lispify[s_ /; AtomQ[s]] := s;

lispify[Unevaluated[2^4 * 3^2]]
```

produces

> {Times, {Power, 2, 4}, {Power, 3, 2}}

My first try had only one difference, namely

```
lispify /@ Unevaluated /@ {args}
```

and sent me down a frustrating rabbit hole until I stumbled on the corrected one above.

Would someone be so kind as to explain the details of both the correct and incorrect solution?

**EDIT:**

As a minor bonus, this enables a nice way to visualize unevaluated expression trees:

```
ClearAll[stringulateLisp];
stringulateLisp[l_List] := stringulateLisp /@ l;
stringulateLisp[e_] := ToString[e];
ClearAll[stringTree];
stringTree[l_List] := First[l][Sequence @@ stringTree /@ Rest[l]];
stringTree[e_] := e;
ClearAll[treeForm];
treeForm = TreeForm@*stringTree@*stringulateLisp@*lispify;
treeForm[Unevaluated[2^4 + 3^2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you for having the forethought of kindly sharing a link to Vellega's notes notebook about controlling evaluation from a 1999 conference. ive been looking for something like this nearly my entire short wolfram life. although somewhat dated pretty much all of it is still relevant today. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must remember that `Unevaluated` only "works" when it is the explicit head of an expression.  In the non-working format the structure looks like:

```
TreeForm @ HoldForm[lispify /@ Unevaluated /@ {arg1, arg2}]
```

[image]

Note that `Unevaluated` *does not* surround `arg1` and `arg2` therefore they evaluate prematurely.

Now compare the working structure:

```
TreeForm @ HoldForm[lispify /@ Unevaluated @ {arg1, arg2}]
```

[image]

Here `Unevaluated` *does* surround `arg1` and `arg2` and evaluation is prevented.

See also:

- [Unexpected behavior of Unevaluated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25266/unexpected-behavior-of-unevaluated/25308#25308)
- [How to Map a function with HoldAll attribute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76558/121)
- [How to map Unevaluated over a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84106/121)

---

By the way you can show [an unevaluated `TreeForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25722/121) by using an additional `Unevaluated` to compensate for an apparent evaluation leak.

```
treeForm =
  Function[expr, TreeForm @ Unevaluated @ Unevaluated @ expr, HoldFirst]
```

Test:

```
2^4*3^2 // treeForm
```

[image]

Also possibly of interest: [Converting expressions to "edges" for use in TreePlot, Graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51629/121)