# How to put a Hold on a variable so it can be set

Tags: function-construction, replacement, hold

I've got a weird problem here....

So I have a function that takes blocks of codes and them uses Map on them and passes them around and then selects and returns the one that is needed.

A simplified dummy of it is given below:

```
In:
SetAttributes[func, HoldAll];
func[exprs__] := Which[Evaluate[Sequence @@ (# & /@ Inactivate[{exprs}])]];
```

Now, using it:

```
(* say every even-numbered index argument is a code block: *)
In: func[a, 1, b, x = 1; 2, c, 0]
Out: Which[a, 1, b, x = 1; 2, c, 0]

In: Simplify[%, a == False && b == True]
Out: x = 1; 2

(* along the line it gets activated *)
In: Activate[%]
Out: 2

In: x
Out: 1
```

Ok, now what if x has been set: x = 9 before the code immediately block-quoted above.

```
In: func[a, 1, b, x = 1; 2, c, 0]
Out: Which[a, 1, b, 9 = 1; 2, c, 0]
```

So by the time it gets to Activate, we have a: Set::setraw error

The Inactivate and SetAttributes[_, HoldAll] makes sure the x does not immediately gets aggressively replaced by 9, but somewhere along the line, the Map, Sequence and Evaluate aggressively replaces it. I haven't tried SetAttribute-ing them all for HoldAll, but is less intrusive way (from the point-of-view of these built-in functions) of holding these replacements??

---

In reality, my func immediately calls Activate, looking more like this very simplified dummy:

```
In: func[exprs__] := Activate[Which[Evaluate[Sequence @@ (# & /@ Inactivate[{exprs}])]];
```

But the step-by-step code further above that I've shown re-produces what I've been getting. Also with immediately above:

```
In: func[a, 1, b, x = 1; 2, c, 0]
Out: Which[a, 1, b, 9 = 1; 2, c, 0]

In: Simplify[%, a == False && b == True]
Out: 2
```

and the `9 = 1;` magically doesn't seem to happen (neither x is 1 nor a setraw error pops up), so I decided it was a poor example to state the case. But the question is the same, is there a less intrusive way?

Comment: C'mon.... It should just be a combination of Unevaluated, Inactivate or something... I just don't wanna be blindly cracking it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88018/121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite following the underlying purpose of this code but here a few thoughts.

1. I believe you can implement the function you wrote more simply as

   ```
   SetAttributes[func, HoldAll];

   func[exprs__] := Which @@ Inactivate[{exprs}];
   ```
2. The evaluation of `x` comes from the fact that [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) does not hold the arguments of the expressions that it inactives, only the heads.  More explicitly the long form of `x = 1` is `Set[x, 1]` which is transformed to `Inactive[Set][x, 1]` and the compound head `Inactive[Set]` does not have a Hold attribute.

To propose a solution I need to understand how you are using this function and how or where your `Set` operations appear generally, rather than in a single example.

As a point of reference your dummy operation would appear to reduce to

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldAll];

func[exprs__] := Which[exprs];
```

But I assume you actually want to perform other manipulations on `exprs` before inserting them into `Which`.  You may want [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html) and [`ReleaseHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) rather than [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) and [`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html).

Another guess at what you might want would be something like this:

```
SetAttributes[func, HoldAll];

func[exprs__] := foo /@ Hold /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}];

func[a, 1, b, x = 1; 2, c, 0]
```

> ```
>   {foo[Hold[a]],
>    foo[Hold[1]],
>    foo[Hold[b]],
>    foo[Hold[x = 1; 2]], 
>    foo[Hold[c]],
>    foo[Hold[0]]}
> ```

Comment: For your (1), yes, I'm aware that you can simply `func[exprs__] := Which @@ Inactivate[{exprs}];` or `func[exprs__] := Which[exprs];` but I'm replicating the process that my actual library is going through and *possiblity* where the semicolon-ed code are being evaluated too soon. As I stated "but somewhere along the line, the Map, Sequence and Evaluate aggressively replaces it"

Comment: As for `func[exprs__] := foo /@ Hold /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}];`... That's interesting, I didn't know that shorthand, I would've done `Hold[foo] & /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}]`

Comment: Alright, I'll try `Hold`-ing every argument

Comment: I've tried your `# & /@ Hold /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}]`, it's different from the usual `Hold[#] & /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}]`... It really passes `Hold` first without evaluating the `#` at all.

Comment: Where did you get the reference for `# & /@ Hold /@ Unevaluated[{exprs}]`?? Map according to the documentation: "Map always effectively constructs a complete new expression and then evaluates it." Meaning, this is preorder passing `#` rather than inorder passing, as that is the only explanation that the `#` doesn't get to evaluate raw.

Comment: MrWizard?? I still want to know where you got that reference for it... Maybe there's an equivalent for `foo & [arg]` ?

Comment: @kozner My primary reference for `Unevaluated` is a presentation by Robby Villegas linked in this answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25308/121 -- I think it will do a better job of explaining the mechanism at work here than I can.  However if after reading it you still have questions I will do my best to answer them.